# InnoDb error in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want my table to create using InnoDB in order to perform a complex transaction to ensure ACID model. This is how I create DB at runtime

```
$fields = array(
                 'trans_id' => array(
                         'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                         'constraint' => 30,
                         'unique' => TRUE
                 ),
                 'detail' => array(
                         'type' => 'TEXT',
                         'null' => FALSE
                 ),
                 'phone' => array(
                         'type' =>'TEXT',
                         'null' => FALSE
                 ),
                 'debit' => array(
                         'type' => 'DOUBLE',
                         'unsigned' => TRUE
                 ),
            'credit' => array(
                         'type' => 'DOUBLE',
                         'unsigned' => TRUE
                 ),
            'balance' => array(
                         'type' => 'DOUBLE',
                         'unsigned' => FALSE
                 ),
                 'timestamp' => array(
                        'type' => 'TIMESTAMP',
                        'default' => ['value' => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', 'string' => false]
                    )
         );
$attributes = array('ENGINE' => 'InnoDB');
$this->dbforge->add_field($fields);
$this->dbforge->create_table('my_table, TRUE, $attributes);
```

gives the error

```
           <h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
        <p>Error Number: 1064</p>
        <p>You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
         that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
        syntax to use near 'Array
             ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = 
       utf8_general_ci' at line 8</p>
        <p>CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `8882177363_table` (
`trans_id` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
`detail` TEXT NOT NULL,
`phone` TEXT NOT NULL,
`debit` DOUBLE UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`credit` DOUBLE UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`balance` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
`timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT Array
   ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = 
 utf8_general_ci</p>
```

However, the code works fine when I don't use attribute array containing 'ENGINE' white creating table.

**PROBLEM RESOLVED**

By changing

```
'timestamp' => array(
                        'type' => 'TIMESTAMP',
                        'default' => ['value' => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', 'string' => false])
```

to

```
'timestamp' => array(
                        'type' => 'TIMESTAMP')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code generate an error in the Sql, in this part:

```
`timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT Array
```

Specifically, `Array` isn't a MySQL's correct string.

Try this:

```
$fields = array(
             'trans_id' => array(
                     'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                     'constraint' => 30,
                     'unique' => TRUE
             ),
             'detail' => array(
                     'type' => 'TEXT',
                     'null' => FALSE
             ),
             'phone' => array(
                     'type' =>'TEXT',
                     'null' => FALSE
             ),
             'debit' => array(
                     'type' => 'DOUBLE',
                     'unsigned' => TRUE
             ),
        'credit' => array(
                     'type' => 'DOUBLE',
                     'unsigned' => TRUE
             ),
        'balance' => array(
                     'type' => 'DOUBLE',
                     'unsigned' => FALSE
             ),
             'timestamp' => array(
                    'type' => 'TIMESTAMP',
                    'value' => '0',
                    'default' => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
                )
     );
```

Comment: Now It gives error - Invalid default value for 'timestamp'

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about `php`, but apparently your error message tells you all the truth.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `8882177363_table` (
`trans_id` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
`detail` TEXT NOT NULL,
`phone` TEXT NOT NULL,
`debit` DOUBLE UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`credit` DOUBLE UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`balance` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
`timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT Array
   ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci
```

The word `Array` in the last field `timestamp` cause the error, you must check your `php` code to remove it.